# How to convert string to symbol in PHP

Tags: php

How to convert a password string to specified symbol like `*` or something else.

I'm currently working on change password page.
I would like to display the password to page, and i want to avoid the password overlook by someone, so i want to covert the password's string to symbol like `*` with same lengths.
An example like `<input type="password" />`.

Sorry for my bad english...

Comment: How are you storing the password that you're able to retrieve it again?  You should be hashing passwords, and not displaying them on the page.

Comment: @Rocket True, although it does depend on the application. I spend a lot of time programming/fixing/shouting at wireless routers, and it really irks me when there is no way to retrieve the currently programmed WPA key from the router, so I am forced to reset it because some idiot end user forgot what they set it to, and then I have to spend 3 hours on the phone explaining to them how to make Windows forget wireless networks so you can rejoin them and set the key again and <heavy breathing> grrrr.....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$output_password = str_repeat ('*', strlen ($input_password));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a simple way to just create a string of asterisks equal to the length of a password:

```
$modified = str_repeat( "*", strlen( "secretpass" ) );

echo $modified; // **********
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't output your password in your HTML, you create an asterix (`*`) representation of your password. This is easily done by the str_repeat function:

```
<?php
$password = "MyPasswordThatIWantToMask";
$maskedPassword = str_repeat("*", strlen($password));
?>
```

Now you just output the `$maskedPassword` as the value of the password field.

However, another very interesting thing: how do you know the users password length? I sincerely hope you hash your passwords rather than having them around plain text.

Answer (score 0):

do it like this:

```
$passwordstring = "password";
$outputpassword = "";
while(strlen($outputpassword)<strlen($passwordstring))
{
    $outputpassword .= "*";
}

echo $outputpassword
```

Comment: Try using build in functions like str_repeat ;).

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use an input of type password but set it to disabled.

`<input type='password' disabled='disabled' value='somepassword' />`

Comment: Right mouse click => inspect item: ooh, that's the password. Ugh.

Comment: @Styxxy Yeah, but he said he wanted to avoid someone walking by and "overlooking" the password, which I assume to mean looking at the screen while you're trying to change your password. Of course, if this is over HTTP and not HTTPS, then I wouldn't use this solution. But for his purposes, this may be sufficient. I probably also wouldn't use this solution if my users were logging in from public locations, as they may forget to log out...

Comment: Okay that way. Then the password field should suffice, you can't see the password anyway.

Answer (score 0):

While there are many answers here demonstrating the user of `str_repeat()`, I sort of doubt that is what you want. After all, any idiot can pad a string with a character, and there would be little point in doing so when one can simply use, as you rightly pointed out, `<input type="password" />` (yes, you could still go get the password from the source code, but then why bother populating an obfuscated field at all? Or not just populating it with a static fixed number of * characters?).

I suspect you are looking for something more like this:

```
<?php

  $thePassword = "thisIsMyPassword";

?>

<input type="text" id="input_user_types_in" value="<?php echo str_repeat('*', strlen($thePassword)); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" id="value_to_post_back" name="value_to_post_back" value="<?php echo $thePassword; ?>" />

<script type="text/javascript">

  var textInput = document.getElementById('input_user_types_in');
  var hiddenInput = document.getElementById('value_to_post_back');

  textInput.onfocus = function() {
    this.value = hiddenInput.value;
  };

  textInput.onblur = function() {
    var i;
    hiddenInput.value = this.value;
    this.value = '';
    for (i = 0; i < hiddenInput.value.length; i++) {
      this.value = this.value + '*';
    }
  };

</script>
```

Have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EBye5/) around with it ;-)